# NetSuite Create a custom list of custom type

Tags: list, netsuite, custom-lists

I need to create a list of a custom type to use as a list of links that have an ordinal field, so I would have a type that has a name, link, and ordinal field, and I would like to have that in a list to access from the site

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under >Customization>List,Records&Fields>Record Types>New, create custom record type. Then to show it as a list on a form, create a custom field with type of 'LIST' at >Customization>List,Records&Fields>. Either as entity, item, transaction body or column field.